# SQL request for having averages from specific periods

Tags: mysql, average

I have a mySQL Database from a weather station.
I've a little website with highcharts to view the results. It works pretty well but for a long period (e.g. one year) I have a very important number of points (one point every 10 minutes).
To have an efficient display, I'm using this query :

```
mysql_query("SET @rownum:=0;");
$query = sprintf("SELECT timestamp,rec_date,temp_in,temp_out,dewpoint,rel_hum_in,rel_hum_out FROM weather WHERE rec_date >= '$Date1' AND rec_date <= '$Date2' AND MOD((@rownum:=@rownum+1),144)=1;");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('text');
```

Date1 and Date2 are given by the user from a datepicker. And I'm using a mysql_fetch_assoc function to store the result in various arrays. So the query return one point every 144 record (one point per day). But it's not an average of the values of the day, it's just one record of the day.

I'd like to have an average of the timestamp, temp_in, temp_out, dewpoint, rel_hum_in and rel_hum_out for each day i.e. 365 averages of each (depending of Date1 and Date2 but it is one year in my example). My problem is that I'm a very newbie in SQL language and I can't find a way to achieve that.
Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AVG()` aggregate function.

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) date, AVG(temp_in) temp_in, AVG(temp_out), ...
FROM weather
WHERE rec_date BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2'
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

use `avg`... for average value, and `date(rec_date)` to have only the date prt of `rec_date` (if it's a `datetime`).

```
select date(rec_date) as day,
       avg(timestamp) as averageTimestamp,
       avg(temp_in) as averageTempIn,
       avg(temp_out) as averageTempOut,
       avg(dewpoint) as averageDewPoint
       --etc
from weather
where year(rec_dat) = 2014--if you wanna data for a year. You may of course also use the between clause
group by date(rec_date)
```